# Remapping/Concatenating in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to reorder/group a set of results using SQL. I have a few fields (which for the example have been renamed to something a bit less specific), and each logical group of records has a field which remains constant - the address field. There are also fields which are present for each address, these are the same for every address.

```
id  forename    surname     address
1   John        These       Address1
2   Lucy        Values      Address1
3   Jenny       Are         Address1
4   John        All         Address2
5   Lucy        Totally     Address2
6   Jenny       Different   Address2
7   Steve       And         Address2
8   Richard     Blah        Address2

address     John    Lucy            Jenny       Steve       Richard
Address1        These   Values          Are         (null)      (null)
Address2        All     Totally         Different   And         Blah
```

For example: John,Lucy,Jenny,Steve and Richard are the only possible names at each address. I know this because it's stored in another location.

Can I select values from the actual records in the left hand image, and return them as a result set like the one on the right? I'm using MySQL if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you precise what you really want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column headings "john", "lucy" etc are fixed, you can group by the address field and use if() functions combined with aggregate operators to get your results:

```
select max(if(forename='john',surname,null)) as john,
       max(if(forename='lucy',surname,null)) as lucy,
       max(if(forename='jenny',surname,null)) as jenny,       
       max(if(forename='steve',surname,null)) as steve,       
       max(if(forename='richard',surname,null)) as richard,
       address
from tablename 
group by address;
```

It is a bit brittle though.

There is also the group_concat function that can be used (within limits) to do something similar, but it will be ordered row-wise rather than column-wise as you appear to require.

eg.

```
select address, group_concat( concat( forename, surname ) ) tenants 
from tablename
group by address;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think what you're trying to do is GROUP BY.

```
SELECT Address,Name FROM Table GROUP BY Name
```

if you want to  select more columns, make sure they're included in the GROUP BY clause.  Also, you can now do aggregate functions, like MAX() or COUNT().

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the question, but from what I understand you can do:

```
SELECT concat(column1,column2,column3) as main_column, address from table;
```